# How to get around .push is not a function in javascript?

Tags: javascript, function, binary, stack

I need to stack the binary. Need to use no-prototype. When using this code, i'm getting the error that remStack.push is not a function. What am I missing here?

```
function Stack() {}
function divideBy2(decNumber) {
  var remStack = new Stack(),
    rem,
    binaryString = '';
  while (decNumber > 0) {
    rem = Math.floor(decNumber % 2);
    remStack.push(rem);
    decNumber = Math.floor(decNumber / 2)
  }
  while (!remStack.isEmpty()) { //{5}
    binaryString += remStack.pop().toString();
  }
  return binaryString;
}
console.log(divideBy2(233));
```

Comment: it should be `remStack = []`  http://codetunnel.com/9-javascript-tips-you-may-not-know/#stack

Comment: Why do you expect the object to have `push` method?

Comment: You wrote a `Stack` class that has no contents. If you want a `push` method, you'll need to write it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out by others, your `Stack` class does not have `push`, `pop`, `isEmpty` functions.

Here is how I would do it (without using any external library and implementing the Stack class using JS Array).

```js
function Stack() {
  this.myStack = [];
  this.push = function(val) {
   this.myStack[this.myStack.length] = val;
  };
  this.isEmpty = function() {
   return this.myStack.length <= 0;
  };
  this.pop = function() {
 return this.myStack.splice(this.myStack.length - 1, 1)[0];
  };
}

function divideBy2(decNumber) {
  var remStack = new Stack(), rem, binaryString = '';
  while (decNumber > 0) {
    rem = Math.floor(decNumber % 2);
    remStack.push(rem);
    decNumber = Math.floor(decNumber / 2)
  }
  while (!remStack.isEmpty()) { //{5}
    binaryString += remStack.pop().toString();
  }
  return binaryString;
}

console.log(divideBy2(233));
```

If you have option to write ES6, this is what I would prefer.

```js
class Stack {
  myStack = [];
  push = val =>  this.myStack[this.myStack.length] = val;
  isEmpty = this.myStack.length <= 0;
  pop = this.myStack.splice(this.myStack.length - 1, 1)[0];
  reduce = reducer => this.myStack.reverse().reduce(reducer);
}

const buildStack = (remStack, decNumber) => {
    if (decNumber > 0) {
      remStack.push(Math.floor(decNumber % 2));
      buildStack(remStack, Math.floor(decNumber / 2));
    }
};

const divideBy2 = decNumber => {
  const remStack = new Stack();
  buildStack(remStack, decNumber);
  return remStack.reduce((acc, v) => `${acc}${v}`, '');
}

console.log(divideBy2(233));
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

With slight modification you could have .

```js
function Stack() {}
function divideBy2(decNumber) {
  var remStack = []//new Stack(),
    var rem,
    binaryString = '';
  while (decNumber > 0) {
    rem = Math.floor(decNumber % 2);
    remStack.push(rem);
    decNumber = Math.floor(decNumber / 2)
  }
  while (!remStack.length == 0) { //{5}
    binaryString += remStack.pop().toString();
  }
  return binaryString;
}
console.log(divideBy2(233));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

[For more info](http://codetunnel.com/9-javascript-tips-you-may-not-know/#stack)

Comment: Thanks for the assist. I'm too new to vote, but this answered my question.

Answer (score 0):

here, I found some mistake.

1. you have to return array from Stack function. Actually you my need to have function not and object. with new operator you are making instance of Stack. Here, in Stack  Object i have made one array variable to return;
2. In array you can not have empty function. You need to count it's value. Here, i  have done <1 condition

   function Stack() { var myarray=[]; return myarray; }
   function divideBy2(decNumber) {
   var remStack = Stack(),
   rem,
   binaryString = '';
   while (decNumber > 0) {
   rem = Math.floor(decNumber % 2);
   remStack.push(rem);
   decNumber = Math.floor(decNumber / 2)
   }
   while (!remStack.length<1) { //{5}
   binaryString += remStack.pop().toString();
   }
   return binaryString;
   }
   console.log(divideBy2(233));